# Cant access the objects in my kivy class, can't use 'app.root' and ‘self.ids’

Tags: python, kivy

I want to call a function but that function has two parameters and can't call the function without the parameters cause python show an error about two missing arguments. I normally access my objects using ‘app.root’ ‘self.ids ‘in this case I can't use these for some certain reasons. I want to call the ‘MyFirebase().sign_up(email=, password=)’ but I need to equal it to the objects in my kivy class. The objects im trying to equal it to is stored at ‘app.root.ids.signup.ids.email.text’ and ‘approot.ids.signup.ids.password.text’ if anyone has an idea how to access these objects I would appreciate. Here is a minimal reproducible example of my code and I am trying to fall the function under ‘thefirebase = MyFirebase()’

```
from kivy.app import App
import requests
import json

class MyFireBase():

    def __init__(self):
        # initialize localId to None, just to be sure it always exists
        self.localId = None


    def sign_up(self, email, password):

            app = App.get_running_app()
            email = email.replace("\n","")
            password = password.replace("\n","")

            # Send email and password to Firebase
            # Firebase will return localId, authToken (idToken), refreshToken
            signup_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?key=" + self.wak
            signup_payload = {"email": email, "password": password, "returnSecureToken": True}
            sign_up_request = requests.post(signup_url, data=signup_payload)
            sign_up_data = json.loads(sign_up_request.content.decode())
            print(sign_up_request.ok)
            print(sign_up_request.content.decode())


            if sign_up_request.ok == True:
                print(sign_up_data)
                refresh_token = sign_up_data['refreshToken']

                self.localId = sign_up_data['localId']
                idToken = sign_up_data['idToken']

                # Save refreshToken to a file
                with open(app.refresh_token_file, "w") as f:
                    f.write(refresh_token)


                app.local_id = self.localId
                app.id_token = idToken




                my_data =  '{"avatar": "profilepic.png", "jobs_done": "", "jobs_posted": ""}'
                post_request = requests.patch("https://moonlighting-bb8ab.firebaseio.com/users/" + self.localId + ".json?auth=" + idToken, data=my_data)
                print(post_request.ok)
                print(post_request.content.decode())

                app.root.current = "create"



            elif sign_up_request.ok == False:

                error_data = json.loads(sign_up_request.content.decode())
                error_message = error_data["error"]['message']
                app.root.ids.signup.ids.signup_message.text = error_message.replace("_", " ")

    def send_user_details(self):
        app = App.get_running_app()
        my_data ={"first name": app.root.ids.create.ids.first_name.text, "last name": app.root.ids.create.ids.last_name.text,
                   "phone number": app.root.ids.create.ids.phone_number.text, "job1": app.root.ids.create.ids.job1.text, "job2": app.root.ids.create.ids.job2.text,
                   "job3": app.root.ids.create.ids.job3.text, "date of birth": app.root.ids.create.ids.date_of_birth.text, "state": app.root.ids.create.ids.state1.text}

        user_details = requests.patch("https://moonlighting-bb8ab.firebaseio.com/users/" + app.local_id + ".json?auth=" + app.id_token,  json.dumps(my_data))
        print(user_details.ok)
        print(user_details.content.decode())

        app.root.current = "main"




    def sign_in_existing_user(self, email, password):
        signin_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=" + self.wak
        signin_payload = {"email": email, "password": password, "returnSecureToken": True}
        signin_request = requests.post(signin_url, data=signin_payload)
        sign_up_data = json.loads(signin_request.content.decode())
        app = App.get_running_app()
        print(signin_request.ok)
        print(signin_request.content.decode())

        if signin_request.ok == True:
            refresh_token = sign_up_data['refreshToken']

            self.localId = sign_up_data['localId']
            idToken = sign_up_data['idToken']
            # Save refreshToken to a file
            with open(app.refresh_token_file, "w") as f:
                f.write(refresh_token)

            # Save localId to a variable in main app class
            # Save idToken to a variable in main app class
            app.local_id = self.localId
            app.id_token = idToken
            # Create new key in database from localId
            # Get friend ID
            # Get request on firebase to get the next friend id
            # --- User exists so i dont need to get a friend id
            # self.friend_get_req = UrlRequest("https://friendly-fitness.firebaseio.com/next_friend_id.json?auth=" + idToken, on_success=self.on_friend_get_req_ok)
            # app.change_screen("home_screen")

            app.root.current = "main"


        elif signin_request.ok == False:
            error_data = json.loads(signin_request.content.decode())
            error_message = error_data["error"]['message']
            app.root.ids.login.ids.login_message.text = error_message.replace("_", " ")


class Server():

    def __init__(self, thefirebase, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        app = App.get_running_app()

        self.thefirebase = thefirebase  # Store the initialised MyFireBase instance

app = App.get_running_app()
thefirebase = MyFireBase()
thefirebase.sign_up(email= app.root.ids.signup.ids.email.text, password=app.root.ids.signup.ids.password.text)

class MyApp(App):
    refresh_token_file = "refresh_token.txt"
    members_list = "members_list.txt"
    thefirebase = MyFireBase()



    def build(self):
        app = App.get_running_app()
        self.thefirebase = MyFireBase()
        self.refresh_token_file = app.user_data_dir + self.refresh_token_file
        return sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code:

```
app = App.get_running_app()
thefirebase = MyFireBase()
thefirebase.sign_up(email= app.root.ids.signup.ids.email.text, password=app.root.ids.signup.ids.password.text)
```

will fail because it is trying to access the `running_app` before there is an app running. Those lines should be deleted.

In your `build()` method you are again calling `App.get_running_app()`, but in that case, the `App` is `self`. So you don't need to call it there either.

Since your desired call references `ids`, you must delay that call until the `App` display is constructed (when the `ids` dictionary is filled). I would suggest changing your `App` class to:

```
class MyApp(App):
    refresh_token_file = "refresh_token.txt"
    members_list = "members_list.txt"
    # thefirebase = MyFireBase() # not needed. it is defined in the build()

    def build(self):
        self.thefirebase = MyFireBase()
        self.refresh_token_file = self.user_data_dir + self.refresh_token_file

        # delay your call to sign_up() until the App is built
        Clock.schedule_once(self.call_signup)

        return sm

    def call_signup(self, dt):
        # now make the desired call to sign_up()
        self.thefirebase.sign_up(email=self.root.ids.signup.ids.email.text, password=self.root.ids.signup.ids.password.text)
```

By the way, you haven't provided a minimal reproducible example, because you have not provided the `kv` file that contains your `id` definitions. So I cannot test my answer.

Comment: I see that there was a suggested edit to move the `return` before the `Clock.schedule_once()`. Any commands in a method that appear after en executed `return` will be ignored.